# Full Screen Video Recording in Front Camera using camera2 api

Tags: android, kotlin, fullscreen, android-camera2, stretching

I have been stuck in this issue for days.

I followed this Android's official camera-sample in Kotlin: 
[android's camera-sample](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/Camera2VideoKotlin)

I raised an issue on github [issue](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/issues/168) on 11 Feb 2020 but haven't received any feedback.

My problem is:

I used the sample as it is and only changed `val cameraId = manager.cameraIdList[0]` to `val cameraId = manager.cameraIdList[1]` for front camera. 
NOTE: It does not happen in rear camera.

The front camera does not work and shows black bar on
devices tested:

- Emulator: Pixel C API 29
- Device: Galaxy Tab S2
- Mode: Portrait

[image]

I wanted a full screen view, so when I don't set the aspect ratio of `AutoTextureView` in the commented line below, the video takes full screen but is now stretched.

```
if (resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
  //I only have portrait mode
} else {
  //textureView.setAspectRatio(previewSize.height, previewSize.width)
}
```

Is there a way to set full screen mode without any stretching or in a correct aspect ratio?

I have been through following solutions in slack and none worked for me:

[Camera 2 : Unable to record video in full screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441252/camera-2-unable-to-record-video-in-full-screen)

[Camera2 API Make Preview Fill Entire View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790052/camera2-api-make-preview-fill-entire-view)

[Android Camera2 API stretching the preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752733/android-camera2-api-stretching-the-preview/44324039#44324039)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working for days. [Camera2 full screen preview and image capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985926/camera2-full-screen-preview-and-image-capture) helped me solve the problem.

Setting `onMeasure` in `AutoFitTextureView` as:

```
override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    val width = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
    val height = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
    if (ratioWidth == 0 || ratioHeight == 0) {
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height)
    } else {
        if (width > ((height * ratioWidth) / ratioHeight)) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, (width * ratioHeight) / ratioWidth)
        } else {
            setMeasuredDimension((height * ratioWidth) / ratioHeight, height)
        }
    }
}
```

> Above code makes the screen full size but had problem of preview not
>   being at the centre

So I translated as follows in `configureTransform(viewWidth: Int, viewHeight: Int)`

```
   // adjust the x and y to centre the preview
   val screenWidth = resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels
   val xShift = (viewWidth - screenWidth)/2

   val screenHeight = resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels
   val yShift = (viewHeight - screenHeight)/2
   matrix.setTranslate(-xShift.toFloat(), -yShift.toFloat())

   textureView.setTransform(matrix)
```